# Do you understand this sublime snippet?

Tags: sublimetext2

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[getElement${1/(T)|.*/(?1:s)/}By${1:T}${1/(T)|(I)|.*/(?1:agName)(?2:d)/}('$2')]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>get</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.js</scope>
    <description>Get Elements</description>
</snippet>
```

I do not know this mean.I understand `$1` ,but what is `(?1:agName)(?2:d) ???`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ones you pointed out are formatted strings for substitutions. They are part of the Sublime Text snippet substitutions, as [documented](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/snippets.html#substitutions) -

```
In addition to the place holder syntax, tab stops can specify more complex operations with substitutions. Use substitutions to dynamically generate text based on a mirrored tab stop.

The substitution syntax has the following syntaxes:

${var_name/regex/format_string/}
${var_name/regex/format_string/options}
```

So in your snippet, these are the substitutions - `${1/(T)|.*/(?1:s)/}`, `${1:T}`, `${1/(T)|(I)|.*/(?1:agName)(?2:d)/}`.